# VUE npm module wrong file path source

Tags: javascript, vue.js, npm

so I have my own npm module made by vue js ***(REPO-A)***, let's say I install this module on my project (vue js too) ***(REPO-B)***. And I use an avatar component from that module, previously I have added an @error handler on my `<img>` tag like this to make the image default when something went wrong with the image resource,

```js
handleErrorImage(e) {
  if (e.type === "error") e.target.src = require("../assets/defaultImage.svg")
}
```

it works as expected if I run on ***REPO-A*** and get the `defaultImage.svg` with the right path, but it's not working if I run on ***REPO-B***, and I tried to look at the network panel, I think if I run on ***REPO-B*** the resource of the `defaultImage.svg` was the wrong path like this

**RUN ON REPO-A**
[image]

**RUN ON REPO-B**
[image]

the question is, how to make the `defaultImage.svg` path load correctly if the avatar component is used in ***REPO-B***, thanks in advance

Comment: You should take a look at `publicPath` in `vue.config.js`

Comment: Hi @IVOGELOV where should I set it, is it in `REPO-A` or `REPO-B`

Comment: `REPO-B` demonstrates that your browser is looking for the SVG image inside the current folder (`js`) - so you should probably set the publicPath to `/`

Comment: @IVOGELOV I've tried to set my `publicPath` to `/` inside `vue.config.js` on `REPO-B`. But still doesn't work, or should be good if I set it on `REPO-A`?

Comment: `REPO-A` is working just fine - no need to change anything. If `publicPath` does not work (I can't tell why without looking at the repo) - you can try putting the SVGs in `src/public` and then reference them using absolute URL instead of `require`.